# Request to Re-open "How Front Line Staff can Help Break a Systemic Racist Hiring Policy"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This post was immediately flagged as off-topic for the Workplace. I will address my concerns towards the reason for putting it on hold rather than the comments it received. This question is related to workplace issues.  It falls under the tags of Hiring and Diversity. It is also not a description of my general situation, but rather a question seeking answers to a very specific issue.

If the wording is not the best--as in unclear--then it should be put on hold for that reason, and then I can clarify the wording.

The idea behind my question is (and I have updated the original question already), "what can non-managerial staff do to help a company see it's own biases, and address those biases?," in particular racial bias.

Now, I'd like to address some of the comments my post received in the case that those comments might be reflecting some of the underlying reasons for holding the question. Systemic bias is actually as common as roads and cars; it's everywhere. To treat it as something special is itself heaping more bias on top of bias. I am not obligated to prove my question because it is a question, and not an answer. Furthermore, these are not allegations as I have not implicated or directed my question to any specific organization! In other words, there is no recipient to my question so how can it be called an allegation?

[How Non-Managerial Staff can Help Break a Systemic Racist Hiring Policy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104258/how-front-line-staff-can-help-break-a-systemic-racist-hiring-policy)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the original question has been deleted by the OP and can therefore no longer be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think this question should be reopened yet, until you can tell us *why* you think the hiring policy is racist.**

The reason you are getting pushback is that we need more information to answer the question properly. There is a difference between overhearing your boss say he refuses to hire anyone who isn't white, and observing that your company is 95% white (which could just mean you are in a region where 95% of the population is white). That statistic is the only reason so far you have given for why you believe there is systemic racism. If you don't have any other evidence to support your beliefs, then the advice you will most likely get is to not say anything until you have more evidence.

And yes, we very often ask users to provide evidence when they are asking how to respond to racist/sexist/discriminatory behavior. These are serious problems that would require serious actions, but taking action if you are making any false assumptions will also result in serious negative consequences for you. We need to be able to judge the legitimacy of your claims so that we can properly advise you on what action to, or not to, take.

Comment: Thank you for your proper explanation, ironically, my question was closed by people not giving proper reasoning, yet claiming I had not give proper reasoning. First, I believe the qualification of such issues as "serious" to be yet a method to sideline such discussions as has occurred exactly here with the holding of my topic. This is also not merely my personal opinion, but is a well understood problem within the problem.  I will comply however due to the pressure put on my question.

Comment: Let me clarify, I do not believe the policy is racist, and by fact I'm almost certain it is not; however I believe it is systemically racist. By that I mean there is an entire complex of issues surrounding my industry, educationally and corporately, which keeps out pretty much everyone but white people. This is "understood" on the corporate side, and I personally have heard in staff meetings upper management raise the issue. I am looking for answers, not discussion. My question is answerable and I could begin answering it right now if it were an open question.

Comment: There are certain individual behaviors, or certain conversations or encouragements that could be used by regular staff to help move an organization out of its group think. Yes I have worded my question polemically, if one views it from the perspective of the majority, however from the perspective of minority it would be considered plain truth and direct. My question is not about determining if systemic racism is present, the question assumes cases where it is already present and it would be up to the reader to determine if this is their situation or not--same as any other question on this site

Comment: I will adjust my question to adapt to some of your concerns, once I get some time.  However i want to say I truly believe my question is not especially serious, nor do I believe it is harsh, or destructive, or lacking any any evidence in the sense that any other question would need evidence.

Comment: I just read the general mandate of Stackexchange. I believe my question even re-worded does not fit the mandate of the overarching vision. Ironically, the founder has a very long and subjective description of what constitutes a good "objective" question. Nothing it objective that is quite obvious, especially in computers; just look at your industry make up. I pull my request however. I also offer a mild apology for causing upset to some people.